# Using JavaScript/Jquery to show forms with the same id/class in Ruby

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to have a button for retweets in my web-application. When I press the button I want a form to display in order to add my own text to the tweet.

I implemented this . However I have a problem: all my forms and buttons contain the same id and class, so you can imagine that when I press a button it will display the first form with that id/class instead of the one that it has to show. How can I show the form that I have to show ?

Here are only the parts of the code that contain retweet part(the other parts are not important I think for the problem but I can post them if someone wants me to) :

```
 <button type="buton" id="retweet-button">retweet</button>
      <%= form_for(current_user.tweets.build,url: retweet_act_path, method: :post, html: { multipart: true, :class => "retweet_form"  }) do |f| %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :original_tweet_id, value: tweet.id %>
      <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "Add a message to the tweet..." %> 
      <%= f.submit "Retweet"%>
      <% end %>
```

And the JS:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {

 $('.retweet_form').hide(); //Initially form wil be hidden.

  $('#retweet-button').click(function() {
   $('.retweet_form').show();//Form shows on button click

   });
 });


</script>
```

How can I show the form that I have to show when pressing a certain button ? (I guess I have to have a different ID for every button and form , but how ? )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understood from the code, you use one button/form pair per tweet. So that, you are able to use tweet ID to generate form ID. To connect button to appropriate form, use `data-*` fields.

Generation of forms and buttons on Rails side (NOTE: syntax highlight is broken):

```
<button type="button" class="retweet-button" data-target-form-id="<%= "#retweet-form-#{tweet.id}" %>">retweet</button>
  <%= form_for(current_user.tweets.build,url: retweet_act_path, method: :post, html: { multipart: true, :class => "retweet_form", id: "retweet-form-#{tweet.id}" }) do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :original_tweet_id, value: tweet.id %>
  <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "Add a message to the tweet..." %> 
  <%= f.submit "Retweet"%>
  <% end %>
```

And JS:

```
$('.retweet_form').hide();
$('.retweet-button').click(function() {
  var formId = $(this).data('target-form-id');
  $(formId).show();
});
```